Modify SharePoint List Schema with Python
I want to periodically add choices to a Sharepoint List with Python, but when I do so the choices are formatted in the same way. I tried to add random colors by

Generating the json schema
unique_values = df['Department'].unique()
colors = {value: generate_random_hex_color() for value in unique_values}

# Define the base structure of the JSON schema
json_schema = {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
        "color": ""
    }
}

# Create the condition string for colors
color_conditions = []
for value, color in colors.items():
    color_conditions.append(f"@currentField == '{value}' ? '{color}'")
color_conditions_str = " : ".join(color_conditions) + " : 'green'"

# Add the color conditions to the JSON schema
json_schema["style"]["color"] = f"=if({color_conditions_str})"

# Add other static styles
json_schema["style"].update({
    "background-color": "#f8f8f8",
    "border": "1px solid",
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "4px 8px 5px",
    "border-radius": "16px",
    "margin": "4px"
})

# Convert the JSON schema to a string
json_schema_str = json.dumps(json_schema, indent=2)




Which results into something like that
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField == 'USER1' ? '#e1ce9c' : @currentField == 'USER2' ? '#4d43ae' : @currentField == 'USER3' ? '#8747aa' :


Applying it to the list

sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_name)
field = sp_list.fields.get_by_title(column_name)
ctx.load(field)
ctx.execute_query()

# Update the field's custom formatter
field.CustomFormatter = json_schema_str
field.update()
ctx.execute_query()

I tried various alterations for hours now, without any effect, the style of the entries never changed when I viewed the list, it's always a white blackground with grey font. Help please!!
